# Google maps markers titles do not show up

Tags: google-maps, marker

Markers titles have suddenly stopped to show up on mouse hover. They show up again only if `draggable` property is set to `true`. Checked this in Google code playground with simple basic example and got same behaviour.

Is my pc or browser going wrong? Any idea?

Comment: There was apparently a new push of the experimental version that broke a bunch of functionality https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6932

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Marker title no longer appears as tooltip on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933046/google-maps-marker-title-no-longer-appears-as-tooltip-on-hover)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the experimental version of the API https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp. The release version https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3 still has the desired behavior.

See this question for more details: [Google Maps Marker title no longer appears as tooltip on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933046/google-maps-marker-title-no-longer-appears-as-tooltip-on-hover)