# Gmap V3 api title only appears for first marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Firefox, marker titles appear only for the first marker that is moused over.  Any subsequent mouseovers yield no title.  Titles work fine with Chrome, IE etc.

There have been several previous questions about this.  (see [Google Maps Marker title no longer appears as tooltip on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933046/google-maps-marker-title-no-longer-appears-as-tooltip-on-hover)

The answers have indicated that this was a problem in the experimental version of the api.

gmaps api issues https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6931 is related.

As the attached [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbarkas/dwrup2ad/10/) shows, **the problem is not necessarily fixed by using &v=3**.

Have I missed something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Titles Fail</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mapDisplay(){
        var locations =  [
            [-42.0, 147.0, "marker 1"],
            [-42.3, 147.9, "marker 2"],
            [-42.2, 147.45, "marker 3"],
            [-42.8, 147.9, "marker 4"]
        ];
            $("#map").css({'height': '600px'});

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var marker, point;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                point = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][4]);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    map: map,
                    title: locations[i][5]
                });

                bounds.extend(marker.position);
            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            if(map.getZoom()> 10){
                map.setZoom(10);
            }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="mapDisplay()">
<div id="map" style="height: 90%; width: 90%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is an API version issue (or a Firefox issue).  The ["frozen version" (currently v3.16)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) fixes it (at least for me) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwrup2ad/14/) [current issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7136)

Answer (score 1):

It is an API version issue.  The ["frozen version" (currently v3.16)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning):

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.0&sensor=false'></script>
```

fixes it (at least for me)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwrup2ad/14/)

[current issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7136) (vote to indicate interest/follow status)

Comment: According to Google the 'stable' version is 3.17 and that version does exhibit the undesirable behavior.  Setting the marker option 'optimized' to false makes this behavior go away, that's a good bit of evidence for whoever at Google will be fixing the problem.

Comment: An optimized marker is render using canvas; a non-optimized marker is rendered as a non-canvas DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is still valid in Firefox 39, but now there is an issue with the mousover addListener event as well.

Adding "optimised:false" to the marker options - as mentioned by RoyHB - not only solves the issue with the title, but also the issue with the mouseover addListener event.