# google map multiple marker tooltip only show on the first marker in firefox 32

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

The following fiddle shows the issue -- if you mouse over a map with multiple pins, only the first pin will show the title on Firefox 32. You have to click outside the div to then get another pin to show a title. I am using the fiddle from the accepted answer on a related question but it doesn't appear to work on ff32.

http://jsfiddle.net/msz08tjx/1/

It works fine on Chrome. Tested on FF32 on Windows and OSX. I also tested on FF31 on a Mac and it has the same issue.

Here's the code from the fiddle:

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false'> </script>
<a href="#" onclick='mapDisplay()'>Show Map</a>
<div id="map" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
```

And here's the JS:

```
function mapDisplay(){  
    var locations =  [[23.862162, 90.400749, "2014-07-21 03:20:32"], [15.88216, 92.480751, "2014-07-21 03:20:32"], [24.852161, 91.450752, "2014-08-04 08:23:42"], [36.782162, 83.380753, "2014-08-06 10:12:10"]];
    //
    if(locations.length > 0)
    {
        $("#map").css({'height': '600px'});

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            //zoom: 8,
            //center: new google.maps.LatLng(((locations[0][0]+locations[locations.length-1][0])/2), ((locations[0][1]+locations[locations.length-1][1])/2)),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

        var marker, point, travelCoordinates = new Array();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            point = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                map: map,
                title: locations[i][2]
            });

            travelCoordinates[i] = point 
            bounds.extend(marker.position); 
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        if(map.getZoom()> 10){
            map.setZoom(10);
        }

        var travelPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: travelCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });

        travelPath.setMap(map); 
    }
    else
    {
        $("#map").empty();
        $("#map").css({'background-color': '','height': 'auto'});
        $("#map").html("No records found");
    }   

}
```

Comment: Curious. All I can suggest is, instead of creating the map in response to a user click, create the map on page load, but don't display it.  Then show/hide it when clicking the link.

Comment: [confirmed issue with the API](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7136)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gmap V3 api title only appears for first marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818060/gmap-v3-api-title-only-appears-for-first-marker)

Comment: I tested the optimize:false setting and that makes it a little better - a few pin titles will show up, but not all. i didn't have any reputation to comment on the other to indicate that it doesn't work on at least FF32 so created a new question that was specific to ff32.

Comment: i did some more testing with the optimize:false option and that does appear to fix the issue on ff and i didn't notice any other issues on other browsers so that's probably the current best workaround.